# MultiValueDictKeyError at /web/tracking/upload/csv/login/next/web/tracking/upload/csv/ 'user'

Tags: html, python, django

tengo este archivo `login.html`

```
<html>
    ...
    </head>
    <body class="container">
        ...
        <form action="" method="post">
            <div>
                <h2>Ingrese sus datos de inicio de sesion</h2>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label class="form-label">Usuario: </label>
                <input type="text" id="user" placeholder="Ingrese su usuario"></input>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label class="form-label">Contraseña: </label>
                <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Ingrese su contraseña"></input>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="but-ingresar">Ingresar</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

La linea que dice `<form action="" method="post">` activa la funcion de python:

```
def post(self, request):
        user = request.POST["user"]
        password = request.POST["password"]
        user = authenticate(request, username=user, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            redirect('localhost:8000/web/tracking/upload/csv')
        else:
            redirect('localhost:8000/web/tracking/upload/csv/login/next/web/tracking/upload/csv/')
```

La cosa es que estaba viendo donde esta el error y no pasa de la primera línea, donde dice `user = request.POST["user"]`
Alguien sabe por qué sucede esto y como se puede arreglar?

Comment: podrias añadir cual es el error reportado? que framework utilizas. flask, django?

Comment: django, el error esta en el titulo

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tienes que añadir el atributo `name`

```
 <div>
      <label class="form-label">Usuario: </label>
      <input type="text" id="user" name="user" placeholder="Ingrese su usuario">
      </input>
 </div>
 <div>
       <label class="form-label">Contraseña: </label>
       <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Ingrese su contraseña">
       </input>
 </div>
```

Es aconsejable obtener los datos del formulario con `get` de modo que sino encuentra el valor devolverá `None` como valor por defecto.

```
def post(self, request):
   user = request.POST.get("user", None)
   password = request.POST.get("password", None)
...
```

Comment: Si, justo ahora me acabo de dar cuenta

Comment: pues si te ha gustado la respuesta +1